# Bezeichnung für Übertreibung ins Gegenteil

Tags: single-word-request, vocabulary

Ich beobachte in Diskussionen in letzter Zeit oft eine Herabsetzung des Gegenübers durch Übertreiben seines Standpunkts ins Extreme.

Beispiel 1:

A: Ich finde, man sollte über ein Tempolimit zumindest nachdenken, denn –
B: Also *ich* finde, dass *überhaupt nichts* gewonnen wird, wenn Sie überall Schrittgeschwindigkeit fordern!

Beispiel 2:

C: Ich denke nicht, dass wir eine Obergrenze für Flüchtlinge brauchen, denn –
D: Im Gegensatz zu Ihnen möchte ich nicht die europäische Bevölkerung durch xy ersetzen!

Wie nennt man diesen rhetorischen Tiefschlag? Da muss es doch ein Wort dafür geben. Es geht mir jetzt auch nicht um Tempolimit oder Flüchtlinge, andere Beispiele sind mir aber nicht eingefallen.

Comment: Erinnert mich in gewisser Weise ans [argumentum ad absurdum](http://www.zjs-online.com/dat/artikel/2014_4_831.pdf). Evtl eine Mischform?

Comment: Das Stilmittel der Übertreibung ins Gegenteil halte ich aber für sehr putzig. *Also ich finde, dass wir erst handeln und dann nachdenken sollten! Schrittgeschwindigkeit jetzt! <Hackenknall>*

Comment: @Iris es beinhaltet zwar passende Elemente, bildet es aber nicht genug ab, um mMn eine Antwort mit diesem Begriff zu rechtfertigen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es gibt die Methode der Übertreibung als [Strohmannargument](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strohmann-Argument):

> Die These des Gegners verzerrt, übertrieben oder falsch darstellen,
>   dann die entstellte These widerlegen und behaupten, dass nun die
>   ursprüngliche These widerlegt sei.

Ziel dabei ist es aber nicht das Gegenüber herabzusetzen, sondern es wird ein neues angebliches Argumente der Gegenseite fingiert (das Argument des Strohmanns), das einfach zu widerlegen ist und beim Gegenüber selbst auch nicht verteidigt werden wird, Es wird dann behauptet, die Widerlegung der Strohmannposition wäre eine Widerlegung der tatsächlichen Position des Diskussionsgegners (siehe auch [Quelle 2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typen_von_Argumenten#Strohmann-Argument))

Comment: Das ist der in der Philosophie übliche Terminus.

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde dies als eine Mischform mehrerer rhetorischer Figuren bezeichnen.

Wie @Iris bereits zeigte scheint es sich hier zunächst um ein **[Strohmannargument](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strohmann-Argument)** zu handeln. Die Vorgehensweise bei diesem ist:

> Person 1 stellt Behauptung Y auf
>
> Person 2 wiederholt Behauptung von Person 1 in einer verzerrten/übertriebener Art und Weise
>
> Person 2 attackiert/widerlegt die verzerrte neue Version der Behauptung
>
> Also ist Behauptung Y falsch

[Quelle](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/169/Strawman-Fallacy)

Gleichzeitig findet sich hier noch ein persönlicher Angriff/Herabsetzung des Gegenübers.

> B: Also ich finde, dass überhaupt nichts gewonnen wird, wenn **Sie** überall Schrittgeschwindigkeit fordern!

könnte man auch ohne Angriff umformulieren in

> B: Also ich finde, dass überhaupt nichts gewonnen wird, wenn überall Schrittgeschwindigkeit gefahren wird!

Dementsprechend denke ich, dass hier auch ein [**argumentum ad hominem**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem) enthalten ist, das durch ein [**argumentum ad populum**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) aufgebaut wird.

> B stellt eine Aussage auf, die der öffentlichen Meinung entspricht (alleine weil sie so absurd ist, dass niemand ihr zustimmen würde) - ad populum
>
> B behauptet, dass A diese Aussage unterstützt/fordert/aus A's Aussage folgt
>
> B impliziert dadurch, dass A dumm/unfähig ist, darum sind Aussagen von A falsch - ad hominem

---

Der Vollständigkeit halber will ich noch auf das [**argumentum ad absurdum**](http://www.rechtslexikon.net/d/argumentum-ad-absurdum/argumentum-ad-absurdum.htm) hinweisen. Dies ist eine

> Art der Argumentation, bei der eine Aussicht (insbes. eine bestimmte
>   Auslegung einer Vorschrift) widerlegt wird, indem man zeigt, dass sie
>   zu abwegigen Ergebnissen führt.

Allerdings denke ich, dass hier das Strohmannargument besser greift.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperbel ist das Stilmittel der Übertreibung, ihr Gegensatz die Untertreibung (wikipedia [hyperbel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbel_(Sprache)))

> Wie nennt man diesen rhetorischen Tiefschlag?

das Gegenargument `lächerlich machen`, es `ins Lächerliche ziehen`

weiters käme in Frage:

`als Karikatur darstellen, Karikaturisierung`

oder auch

`Ironisierung`, `Satirisch darstellen`, `Satirisierung`

Answer (score 0):

Bei beiden Beispielen würde ich von *Gesprächsverweigerung* sprechen, von *unverhohlenem Unwillen*, von *komplettem Blockieren*, auch von *jmd. das Wort abschneiden*. Umgangssprachlich nennt man all das wohl *abbügeln*.

Im Gegensatz zu Vickel würde ich im diesem Fall nicht von einem "Stilmittel" sprechen - denn wo wäre hier der Stil? - sondern von einer rhetorischen Figur. Vielleicht könnte man die Äußerungen von B und D als das Abbilden des Unmöglichen interpretieren, dann wäre es ein **Adynaton**. Ganz allgemein äußern B und D **Antithesen**. Dass ich bei B und D außerdem noch an Phrasendrescherei denke, also an **Floskeln**, ist ... äh ... mein persönliches Ding. ;-)

Comment: Auch Sophisma is eine Kunst https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophisma

Answer (score -1):

Eigentlich sprechen Sie zwei verschiedene Aspekte unterschiedlicher Reaktionen (schlechter Argumentation) an. Zum einen dieses Überzeichnen von Thesen und Argumenten und zum anderen statt der Kraft schlagender Argumente sich lieber für den persönlichen Angriff, die Beleidigung zu entscheiden.

Zu Letzterem lernte ich erst vor einigen Wochen das "argumentum ad hominem" kennen, über das Sie genauer bei Wikipedia nachlesen können:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem

Das trifft es schon ziemlich gut auf den Kopf, wenn jemand nur noch "ad hominem" antwortet.

Auch sehr empfehlenswert: der wissenschaftliche Blick, eine gut und verständlich gemachte Analyse von MailLab, die deine Frage aufgreift und in 2 Videos ganz sachlich, nüchtern die Mechanismen von "Bullshit" erklärt - nebst den verschiedenen Fachbegriffen/Fremdwörten.

Dazu empfehle ich (selbst sehr überzeugt) dieses Video auf YouTube anzuschauen:  https://youtu.be/qTKat-O7F7g
... und "im Thema bleibend" auch noch dieses: https://youtu.be/AlSmcBbT15Y

Mai Thi Nguyen-Kim, die Betreiberin des YouTube-Chanels "maiLab", steht dabei für sehr gute, überwiegend neutrale und leicht verständliche Videos, in denen sie sich um einen nüchternen Blick auf viele Fragen, Thesen und Behauptungen unserer Zeit bemüht - immer im Blick auf Beweise und wissenschaftliche Erkenntnisse - die sie dann auch gut erklärt und mit Quellen belegt ...

Alles in allem ein spannendes Themenfeld und sicherlich auch sehr nützlich, um den ein oder anderen "Mist" besser einzuordnen

Comment: Beide Beispiele von Kurtibert sind aber eben keine Argumenta ad hominem. Ein klassisches Beispiel wäre "Ja, wenn man dumm ist, befürwortet man X." Die Werbung hier für den Youtube-Kanal finde ich auch sehr grenzwertig. Daher -1

Comment: Ich korrigiere deinen Beitrag, denn der Youtube Kanal heist "maiLab" und die Autorin heißt Mai Thi Nguyen-Kim.

Comment: Mit einem Verweis auf maiLab-Videos rennt man bei mir offene Türen ein. :-D